# PHP - fopen(): Failed to Open Stream on uploaded file

Tags: php, fopen, fgetcsv

Im trying to upload a csv file then insert its contents into my database. I can successfully upload the file but I am having an error in my insert query. Here's a part of the code:

```
//Upload the file
$file_path = "uploads/";     
$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
$files = pathinfo($file_path,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$uploadstatus   = 1;
$found          = 0;

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
// check if the file being submitted is a csv file
$file_type=$_FILES['uploaded_file']['type'];
if ($files=="CSV") {
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
    $uploadstatus = 1;
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('File upload successful.')</script>";
} else{
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('File upload failed. Please check then re-upload file.')</script>";
}
}


$filename = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
if (file_exists($file_path.$filename) && $uploadstatus) {
    if (!$found) {
        include('conn.php');

        //get the file 
        $handle = fopen($filename,"r");

            do { 
                if (isset($data[0])) { 
                    $data0  =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[0]);  //rcode
                    $data1  =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[1]);  //pcode
                    $data2  =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[2]);  //mcode
                    $data3  =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[3]);  //bcode
                    $data4  =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[4]);  //ecode
                    $data5  =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[5]);  //filetype
                    $data6  =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[6]);  //rec_count
                    $data7  =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[7]);  //gs_count
                    $data8  =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[8]);  //be_count
                    $data9  =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[9]);  //qc_count
                    $data10 =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[10]); //tt_count
                    $data11 =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[11]); //rm_count
                    $data12 =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[12]); //sc_count
                    $data13 =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[13]); //in_count
                    $data14 =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[14]); //en_count
                    $data15 =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[15]); //co_count
                    $data16 =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[16]); //ve_count
                    $data17 =   mysql_real_escape_string($data[17]); //editing


                    $query =  "INSERT INTO tbltest (rcode,pcode,mcode,bcode,ecode,filetype,rec_count,gs_count,be_count,qc_count,tt_count,rm_count,sc_count,in_count,en_count,co_count,ve_count,ed_count) 
                               VALUES ('$data0','$data1','$data2','$data3','$data4','$data5','$data6','$data7','$data8','$data9','$data10','$data11','$data12','$data13','$data14','$data15','$data16','$data17') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rec_count=values(rec_count),gs_count=values(gs_count),be_count=values(be_count),qc_count=values(qc_count),tt_count=values(tt_count),rm_count=values(rm_count),sc_count=values(sc_count),in_count=values(in_count),en_count=values(en_count),co_count=values(co_count),ve_count=values(ve_count),ed_count=values(ed_count)";

                    mysql_query ($query,$connect);
                }     
            } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,"|")); 
        }   
    }
}
```

The result of the echo is the correct file, but I get an error that says `fopen(): failed to open stream: No such file or directory` and `fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given`.

Comment: may be the path is wrong.

Comment: i have also tried echoing the whole file + path, and its correct

Comment: if u access the path from ur, what you r getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to open a file that doesn't exist.

The function `move_uploaded_file` does exactly what it says - it *moves* a file that has been uploaded. Once you've called this function the file no longer exists in the temporary upload area.

Change this bit:

```
$filename = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
if (file_exists($file_path.$filename) && $uploadstatus) {
    if (!$found) {
        include('conn.php');

        //get the file 
        $handle = fopen($filename,"r");
```

to:

```
$filename = $file_path;
if (file_exists($filename) && $uploadstatus) {
    if (!$found) {
        include('conn.php');

        //get the file 
        $handle = fopen($filename,"r");
```

Comment: It is als worth noting that the path the file is moved to should be an **absolute** path, currently the path is simply `uploads/{fiename}` which may cause issues for `move_uploaded_file`

Answer (score -1):

files are NOT stored under their original name.

This is the actual file:

```
 $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']
```

Read more in the fine manual:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: I don't see any code that uses fgetcsv() in your example.

Comment: I also don't see any mention of the value of $file_path. It is hard to help with such an incomplete code snippet.

Comment: $file_path = "uploads/";  <-- Is that working alright?
Anyway: You are opening another file that you test for. Look:
test: if (file_exists($file_path.$filename) && $uploadstatus) {
 and then later: $handle = fopen($filename,"r"); Try instead $handle = fopen($file_path.$filename,"r");